# How to create nohup.out file of webpack project with react js in linux os on live server

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Actuly i have need to run webpack(with react js) project using nohup on live server in linux(ubuntu) OS.

I have the below questions -

1. what is cmd  for create nohup.out file (with example)
2. How to run nohup.out file(with example)

Comment: Hi Ramesh,  can you clarify?  A nohup.out file is not useful to webpack/react and you don't run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. what is cmd for create nohup.out file  and run :--

```sh
nohup npm start &  ||nohup npm start --production &  ||nohup npm start --development &
```

2. How to read nohup.out file in console :--

```sh
tail -f nohup.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04, nohup doesn't work with `npm start` command although works with with VueJS `npm run serve` or Angular `ng serve --open`. NPM option package to keep your app alive is PM2. But, in order to run nohup you could follow this:

First, install the following package. Serve package must be installed globally on the system/server:

```
$ sudo -H npm install -g serve
```

Change directory to your project app directory

```
$ cd /var/www/path-to-directory
```

If you have already selected server port, run the following command. REMEMBER to keep nohup ID saved in oder to kill process when would be needed. Notice in this case, "nohup" has to be run specifying the port - replace PORT with its number:

```
$ nohup serve -s build -l PORT > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

`nohup` stands for "no hangup." nohup is a POSIX command to ignore the hangup signal.

The hangup signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes of logout.

`nohup` also means Do not terminate this process even when the stty is cut off

`> /dev/null` means: stdout goes to /dev/null (which is a dummy device that does not record any output)

`2>&1` means: stderr also goes to the stdout (which is already redirected to /dev/null)

You may replace &1 with a file path to keep a log of errors, e.g.: 2>/tmp/myLog

`&` at the end means: run this command as a background task

Killing nohub process # 2nd column from listing

```
$ ps -ef | grep nodejs
```

Copy th ID and kill the process

```
$ sudo kill <id>
```